# OAuthForbiddenException: You are not a sandbox user of this client - Instagram login in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, instagram

I'm creating a mvc 5 web application using .Net and C# and I need to do OAuth using **Instagram** to get Images of particular user who login via Instagram.

I'd also created and get my client_Id and client_secret on Instagram developer portal.

My Instagram developer "Client Status" is "Sand Box".

And my problem is, If I login in with my developer account I get my Instagram images.

But if I log-in with any other Instagram user I get an error response after Successful authentication on Instagram

My Error Response after Instagram Authentication in json format is below

```
{"error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "code": 403, "error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}
```

Awaiting for prompt response.

Thanks,
Jatin

Answer (score 1):

Because your app is in sandbox mode, you can only use it with specific accounts.
You need to add the account you want to test your app with, as a sandbox user.

See this page: https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Please provide more information

Answer (score 0):

As what stated by @tompec. Apps in Sandbox Mode are restricted to a limited number of users and media, for developing and testing purpose.

So, if you want that all users can able to login with your functionality, you need to go live, you will need to submit your application for review and approval once reviewed, you will be able to request from other account too.

Doc: [Permissions Review](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/)